# extend UIView or UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, extend

I'm trying to extend my `UITableView` or `UIView` 's height by clicking a button to show more details in it as same as the option in the App Store when you want to see more updates of the app. Is it any tutorial for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I'm gonna answer my own question. probably there is a easier way for this but if someone has the same question u can use this : 
1. Add a `UIButton` on the view
2. In the .h file make a `NSInteger i` and in the `viewDidLoad` give `i=0`. 
3. When user click the invisible button on the `UIView` :

```
-(IBAction) clickMyView (id) sender {
if (i==0){
i=1;
[self changeView];
}
else{
i=0;
[self changeView];
}
```

4.Set `chageView`:

```
-(void) changeView{
if (i==0){
        [UIView beginAnimations : nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];        

        // Change the view back to it's normal size here
        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
else{
            [UIView beginAnimations : nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];

            // Change the view to the new size here
            [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```